Troubleshooting Docker Startup Failure

docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error preparing rootfs: remount-private dst=/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/79b3422c27abb4493259384774bcb432354ca1239566e21b21508d0d7cda8623, flags=0x40000: permission denied: unknown.

I am trying to start docker container on Ubuntu virtual machine but I am getting the above error, I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.
I have installed docker from official installtion guide of docker hub.
